# Python script on Raspberry runs out of memory while listening (webserver or websocket)

Tags: python-2.7, websocket, python-requests, raspberry-pi, out-of-memory

on my RPi's I need an "event" within my python script which can be triggered from other devices, in order to set high a GPIO output for 60s. First I tried it with a websocket:

```py
def run_tcp_listener():

   global PINO_MOB  # = 16

   server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
   server_socket.bind(('', 8123))
   server_socket.listen(1)

   while True:
      GPIO.output(PINO_MOB, GPIO.LOW)
      client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()

      message = client_socket.recv(16)
      if message == 'Gong_Familie':
         GPIO.output(PINO_MOB, GPIO.HIGH)

      client_socket.close()
      time.sleep(60)
```

It starts in a separate task:

```py
      proc = Process(target=run_tcp_listener)
      proc.start()
```

Basicly its working fine, but I'm running out of memory in less than 1h. It looks like that:
[Memory Overview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6telu.png)

When the swap file begins to grow, soon everything stuck. No reaction on the touchscreen and even via ssh no reaction, no re-login possible.

Furthermore I must say its Python v2.7. I had some trouble after updating to v3.x so I switched back again. The system is jessie lite (kiosk mode).

I also tried it by triggering via a get request

```py
def run_http_listener():
   # Die Adresse und Portnummer, an der der Server lauschen soll
   server_address = ('', 8124)

   # Erstellt eine Instanz des HTTP-Servers mit der eigenen Handler-Klasse
   httpd = HTTPServer(server_address, MyHTTPRequestHandler)

   # Startet den Server und laesst ihn auf eingehende Anfragen warten
   httpd.serve_forever()



# eigene Handler-Klasse, die von BaseHTTPRequestHandler erbt
class MyHTTPRequestHandler(BaseHTTPRequestHandler):

   # wird aufgerufen, wenn eine HTTP GET-Anforderung empfangen wird
   def do_GET(self):

      global PINO_MOB

      # Setzt den HTTP-Statuscode auf 200 (OK)
      self.send_response(200)

      # Setzt den Content-Type Header
      self.send_header('Content-type', 'text/html')
      self.end_headers()

      # Aktiviert GPIO (Mobotix) fuer 60s
      if self.path == '/Gong_Familie':
         GPIO.output(PINO_MOB, GPIO.HIGH)
         time.sleep(60)
         GPIO.output(PINO_MOB, GPIO.LOW)
```

This also starts in a separate task:

```py
      proc = Process(target=run_http_listener)
      proc.start()
```

Same result, filling memory soon crushs the system. Without a listener it runs 24/7 for months without any problems.

Any ideas how to fix that?

Best Regards

```
                                                                   .
```